# My layer won't appear in QGIS using PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am working with a "cities" layer (polygons) in a PostgreSQL 9.1 database.  When I use the following query in PostGIS:

```
select st_buffer(st_union(st_centroid(cities.geom)),1500) geom from "my_layer" cities
```

I have no problem with displaying the layer in QGIS.

When I  use this syntax:

```
select st_union(st_buffer(st_centroid(cities.geom),1500)) geom from "my_layer" cities
```

No error is generated in PostGIS, the generated table has one element (as expected) the table can be opened in qgis, its extent "seems" OK **but nothing appears on the screen ...**

I checked objects with a **ST_IsValid** query and found no error.  I tried adding an id but nothing changed.  I tried these two queries in PostgreSQL 9.5 **and had no problem at all**.

What could I be doing wrong, why do I have this behavior using PostgreSQL  9.1, and what could be the workaround?

**PS** : PostGIS version is 1.5.3 in the first case (PostgreSQL 9.1) and 2.2.1 in the second case (I suppose it must be important ...)

Comment: PG 9.1 is extremely old. The PostGIS installations which supported 9.1 are also very old. Comparing a 9.5 install to 9.1 is like comparing a Playstation with an Atari 2600. If you edit the question to include the PostGIS versions involved, you'll see why this is not really a "why" issue. The workaround would be to use modern software.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realize the 9.1 is quite old, but i wanted to find a 'light' workaround not implying to upload my data to a newer Postgres server ...

Comment: There have been five major releases and 41 minor ones since PostGIS 1.5.3. If you want a lightweight solution, find and install the last PostGIS that supported PG 9.1 (you might need to upgrade your 9.1 to a terminal build)